# Apache .htaccess if doesn't work with local assigned env vars

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess

I want to set an env var in .htaccess file. The first line is changed by a script whenever the site is set to maintenance mode.

```
# maintenance mode on/off
SetEnvIf maintenance 0

<If "env('maintenance') == '1'">
    ErrorDocument 503 /maintenance.html
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/maintenance.html
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(GET|HEAD|POST|PROPFIND|PUT) [NC]
       RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=#####our public ip address from service net###
       RewriteRule ^.*$ - [R=503,L]


</If>
<Else>
       # normal mode
       DirectoryIndex app.php

       # to the front controller "/app.php" but be rewritten to "/app.php/app".
       <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
           Options -MultiViews
       </IfModule>

       <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
           RewriteEngine On
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
           RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
           RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
           RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
           RewriteRule .? - [L]
           RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
       </IfModule>

       <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
           <IfModule mod_alias.c>
               RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
           </IfModule>
       </IfModule>
</Else>
```

I can't activate maintenance mode by setting first line to "1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> SetEnvIf maintenance 0
> ```

You have the syntax wrong... you are trying to use `SetEnv` (mod_env) syntax with the more complex `SetEnvIf` (mod_setenvif) directive. So, either use [`SetEnv`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_env.html#setenv):

```
SetEnv maintenance 1
```

OR, use [`SetEnvIf`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif):

```
SetEnvIf ^ ^ maintenance=1
```

The first `^` is a regex that "matches" any HTTP request header and the second `^` is a regex that "matches" against that header. In other words, this is always successful and the env var is always set.

However, you may *need* to use `SetEnvIf` here since `SetEnv` is processed much later (sometimes too late). (`<If>` expressions are evaluated early, but *merged* late.)

Comment: Thanks for Your answer. 
`SetEnvIf ^ ^ maintenance=1` doesn't work. It only works when I put the line in the apache-conf file of the vhost, but I wanted to put it in the `.htaccess`-File. I don't want to reload apache config.

Comment: It seems the `<If>` in the .htaccess-file example above is processed earlier than the `SetEnvIf`.

Comment: `SetEnvIf` is certainly processed _before_ the `<If>` expression. It is more likely you have a conflict with other directives. If you have mod_rewrite directives in `.htaccess` then these may trigger an additional pass through the rewrite engine, at which time these env vars get renamed with a `REDIRECT_` prefix. (If this is the case then you can perhaps check for `REDIRECT_maintenance` instead, but this could perhaps be avoided by updating other parts of the `.htaccess` config.) Please update your question with the complete `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Yes, that was the solution, sorry for the beginners fault. For the sake of readability I thought the lines could be omitted. 
(And for better readability I wanted to solve it with `<If>` and `<Else>`)